# Foreign Key Constraint Failed - Even when I try to manually add data

Tags: sql, db-browser-sqlite

I am studying SQL in my data science degree program, and the assignment is to perform SQL queries for the first time.  In order to do that, I have to paste the SQL starter code in and run it.  However, when I do, I hit an error that I can't solve.  My class is online and my professor hasn't responded and, since this isn't part of the graded part of the assignment, I figured I'd try here to get help on this error.

*Edit*: It was pointed out that I didn't include all of the tables.  Please see full code for all tables and all data.  I was trying to avoid flooding this post with a lot of lines of code, but it seems I left out pertinent information.  See below.

The tables were created with these blocks of code:

```
create table section (
    course_id   varchar(8),
    sec_id          varchar(8),
    semester    varchar(6) check (semester in ('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer')),
    year    numeric(4,0) check (year >1701 and year < 2100),
    building     varchar(15),
    room_number     varchar(7),
    time_slot_id    varchar(4),
    primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
    foreign key (course_id) references course on delete cascade,
    foreign key (time_slot_id) references timeslot on delete no action,
    foreign key (building, room_number) references classroom on delete set null
);

create table teaches (
    ID      varchar(5),
    course_id   varchar(8),
    sec_id      varchar(8),
    semester    varchar(6),
    year    numeric(4,0),
    primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
    foreign key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year) references section on delete cascade,
    foreign key (ID) references instructor on delete set null
);

create table instructor (
    ID varchar(5),
    name varchar(20) not null,
    dept_name varchar(20),
    salary  numeric(8,2) check (salary >10000),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (dept_name) references department on delete set null 
);
```

Then, I added data to instructor and section with the follow.  Side note, I had to go in and manually set the time_slot_id as a primary key to avoid getting an error.

```
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Innovation Hall', '101', 10);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Innovation Hall', '327', 30);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Exploratory Hall', '202', 20);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Research Hall', '302', 20);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Arts Center', '212B', 100);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Research Hall', '310', 30);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Innovation Hall', '121', 10);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Innovation Hall', '321', 20);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Arts Center', '120A', 100);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Exploratory Hall', '231', 20);
INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('Innovation Hall', '220', 30);

INSERT INTO department VALUES ('CDS', 'Research Hall', 100000);
INSERT INTO department VALUES ('Music', 'Arts Center', 70000);
INSERT INTO department VALUES ('History', 'Arts Center', 50000);
INSERT INTO department VALUES ('Geography', 'Exploratory Hall', 60000);
INSERT INTO department VALUES ('Biology', 'Exploratory Hall', 85000);
INSERT INTO department VALUES ('Physics', 'Innovation Hall', 90000);
INSERT INTO department VALUES ('Math', 'Exploratory Hall', 55000);

INSERT INTO course VALUES ('CDS-101', 'Intro to CDS', 'CDS', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('CDS-130', 'Computing for Scientists', 'CDS', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('CDS-302', 'Databases', 'CDS', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('CDS-303', 'Data Mining', 'CDS', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('MUS-100', 'Fundamentals of Music', 'Music', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('HIS-101', 'History of Western Civilization', 'History', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('GGS-101', 'Major World Regions', 'Geography', 4);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('BIO-101', 'Intro to Biology', 'Biology', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('BIO-301', 'Genetics', 'Biology', 4);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('PHY-101', 'Intro to Physics', 'Physics', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('PHY-403', 'Quantum Mechanics', 'Physics', 4);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('MAT-110', 'Probabilities', 'Math', 3);
INSERT INTO course VALUES ('MAT-114', 'Calculus', 'Math', 4);

INSERT INTO prereq VALUES ('CDS-130', 'CDS-101');
INSERT INTO prereq VALUES ('MAT-114', 'MAT-110');
INSERT INTO prereq VALUES ('PHY-403', 'PHY-101');
INSERT INTO prereq VALUES ('CDS-302', 'CDS-130');
INSERT INTO prereq VALUES ('CDS-302', 'PHY-403');
INSERT INTO prereq VALUES ('CDS-303', 'CDS-302');
INSERT INTO prereq VALUES ('CDS-303', 'MAT-114');

INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('11111', 'Turing', 'CDS', 950000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('11112', 'Widom', 'CDS', 100000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('12121', 'Mozart', 'Music', 75000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('22222', 'Heraclitus', 'History', 65000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('12345', 'Eratosthenes', 'Geography', 55000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('54321', 'Crick', 'Biology', 88000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('33333', 'Newton', 'Physics', 80000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('44444', 'Euler', 'Math', 77000);
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('55555', 'Euclid', 'Math', 77000);

INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('A', 'M', 8, 0 , 9, 15);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('B', 'M', 10, 0 , 11, 15);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('C', 'T', 8, 0 , 9, 15);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('D', 'T', 10, 0 , 11, 15);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('E', 'T', 11, 15 , 12, 30);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('F', 'W', 9, 0 , 10, 15);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('G', 'R', 8, 0 , 10, 15);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('H', 'R', 15, 0 , 16, 15);
INSERT INTO timeslot VALUES ('I', 'F', 9, 0 , 10, 15);

INSERT INTO section VALUES ('CDS-101', '1', 'Fall', 2019, 'Research Hall', '310', 'A');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('CDS-130', '1', 'Fall', 2019, 'Innovation Hall', '121', 'B');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('CDS-302', '1', 'Fall', 2019, 'Innovation Hall', '327', 'C');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('CDS-302', '2', 'Spring', 2019, 'Innovation Hall', '321', 'C');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('MUS-100', '1', 'Fall', 2019, 'Arts Center', '120A', 'A');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('HIS-101', '1', 'Fall', 2019, 'Arts Center', '212B', 'B');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('GGS-101', '1', 'Fall', 2019, 'Exploratory Hall', '202', 'D');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('BIO-101', '2', 'Fall', 2019, 'Exploratory Hall', '231', 'E');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('PHY-403', '1', 'Spring', 2019, 'Innovation Hall', '220', 'F');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('BIO-101', '2', 'Fall', 2020, 'Exploratory Hall', '231', 'C');
INSERT INTO section VALUES ('PHY-403', '1', 'Spring', 2020, 'Innovation Hall', '220', 'D');
```

I didn't have a problem.  Finally, I tried to run this:

```
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('11111', 'CDS-101', '1', 'Fall', 2019);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('11112', 'CDS-130', '1', 'Fall', 2019);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('12121', 'MUS-100', '1', 'Fall', 2019);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('54321', 'BIO-101', '2', 'Fall', 2019);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('33333', 'PHY-403', '1', 'Spring', 2019);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('44444', 'MAT-114', '2', 'Fall', 2019);
```

The error occurred on the last line.  I always get:

Result: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
At line 1: *(Note: I tried re-running it by itself afterwards, thus the "Line 1")*
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('44444', 'MAT-114', '2', 'Fall', 2019);

I checked over each constraint, looked at each column, and couldn't figure it out.  I even went in and entered the data manually in the "Browse Data" tab within DB Browser Lite; while I was able to enter the first 4 values, when I try to enter anything for year, I get the same error in a popup box.  Even when I click in the box, leave it blank, then try to click out, I get the same error.  See image.

Please assist... I'm lost at this point and quite frustrated.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You don't show the `instructor` table, but if you don't have the appropriate rows, then you cannot insert into `teaches`.

Comment: Thank you; I edited the original post to include the instructor table as well.

Comment: Your `CREATE ...` code misses at least one `)`. And the `department` table.

Comment: I edited to add the ), it was a missed line on my copy/paste job.  Also, I can include all the fields, I was trying to focus on the ones that seemed to be involved here.  I can add the total fields to this post as well if that's necessary.  This is my first attempt ever to use SQL, my apologies for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. the issue, and
2. how to work out what the issue is.

Let's start with 2).

The error message is:

> Result: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
>   At line 1:
>   INSERT INTO teaches VALUES ('44444', 'MAT-114', '2', 'Fall', 2019);

That tells us to look at the foreign keys defined on the `teaches` table.

There are 2:

- ID references the ID in instructor table (aside: maybe call this instructor_id instead of ID, it'll make more sense in 6 weeks when you come back to look at it).
- course_id, sec_id, semester, year reference the section table.

There is, in your data, an instructor with ID '44444', so that's probably not the problem.

But it doesn't look like there's a row in `section` with `'MAT-114', '2', 'Fall', 2019` and that is likely your problem.

Note also that there's not one for 'MTH-114' like in the image, either.